# Compile Web User Control to Custom Control namespace name could not be found?

Tags: webusercontrol

Example aspx code:

my sample code

**<%@ Register TagPrefix="XF" Namespace="MyNameSPace" %>**

i want to register the tag in my controls, but why it said the namespace could not be found? any ideal?

Comment: where's the example? 
Are you referencing the right assembly?

Comment: sorry about that, i am not sure with the namespace, is that refer to the assembly or i can simply apply a namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are either missing the assembly attribute or you are trying to register a usercontrol without the src attribute:

Real world working examples from a current project of mine:

A user control (.ascx):

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="FooDialog" Src="FooDialog.ascx" %>
```

A webcontrol (defined in a class with no designer file):

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ie" Namespace="Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls" %>
```

Comment: i have add in those thing:

<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"CodeFile="XFButton.ascx.cs" Inherits="XFButton" ClassName="XF.XFButton" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="XF" Namespace="XF" Assembly="App_Web_xfbutton.ascx.cdcab7d2" %>

but its still can't work

Comment: I'll try to correct your code, you are getting the markup mixed up. You want to place a control you've defined elsewhere in a asp-page right? 
At top of aspx-file:
<%@ Register TagPrefix="XF" TagName="XFButton" Src="XFButton.ascx" %>

Below inside the body of the page you should write:

<XF:XFButton id="xButton" runat="server" />

Comment: well, i know the problem of cause of the error already.. we should not put this in ascx..                                              [ToolboxData("<{0}:WebCustomControl1 runat=server></{0}:WebCustomControl1>")]